# Does this special identity matrix have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

recently I stumbled upon the problem of defining a diagonal matrix whose elements are identity matrices of $dim = n$, where $n$ is the column/row index. For example, for $n=3$:

$\mathbb{I}_3 = \left[{\begin{array}{ccc}
  I_1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & I_2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & I_3
  \end{array} }\right]$,

and the subscript indicates the size of the matrix, i.e., $I_2$ is a $2\times 2$ identity matrix and so on.

This definition may look silly, but I need a matrix with this property to explicitly define the direct sum of matrices with a notation that's more usual than $\bigoplus_i^n$.

So, $\mathbb{I}_n$ does have a special name?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, your example is $I_6$.

Comment: It looks like, but $\mathbb{I}_3$ is actually a 3x3 matrix, where the elements of the diagonal are progressively larger identity matrices. This shape is neccessary for the mathematical properties I need.

Comment: You mean, it is not a block notation, but a matrix of which the entries are matrices?

Comment: Precisely! The 1st element is a 1x1 identity matrix. The 2nd element on the diagonal is a 2x2 identity. The 3rd is a 3x3 identity and so on. So, expanding the elements back into full matrices, the full dimension of $\mathbb{I}_n$ is $n!$.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for has/needs a special name. Generally you talk about matrices built out of smaller matrices as being "block matrices" and then you use your arguments about how to compute with the blocks.

Answer (score 1):

There’s not a special unique name, but in general, $\mathbb{I}_{n} = I_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$.

In your example, $n=3$ so $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} = 6$

Comment: I see... I thought this couldn't be new, probably some Russian or French mathematician would already had defined this and it could be referred by its name. But thanks!